# How to overcome dbContext not being thread safe for this usecase

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have several background tasks that run on my .net core application to update a postgres DB.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                        {
                            var sportEvents = Sports.getEvents()
                            var tasks = new List<Task>();
                            foreach (var sportEvent in sportEvents)
                            {
                                DataContext dbContext1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                                tasks.Add(Fanduel.ProcessEvent(sportEvent, logger, dbContext1));
                            }
                            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                            await Task.Delay(0, stoppingToken);
                        }
                }
            });
        }
```

and then the processEvent code

```
public static async Task ProcessEvent(SportEvent sportEvent, ILogger logger, DataContext dbContext)
{
    //processing code here unrelated to database...
    //...

    string key = marketId + "_" + selectionId.ToString() + "_" + handicap.ToString();
                                FanduelPosition fanduelPosition = 
    dbContext.FanduelPositions.Where(s => s.Id == key).FirstOrDefault();
    if (fanduelPosition is not null)
    {
        fanduelPosition.OddsDecimal = oddsDecimal;
        fanduelPosition.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    else
    {
        FanduelPosition newPosition = new FanduelPosition(selectionId, marketId, fdId, sportEvent.EventId, betCategory.ToString(), handicap, oddsDecimal, participant, betPosition);
        await dbContext.AddAsync<FanduelPosition>(newPosition);
    }
}
```

This is the code related to the dbContext within `ProcessEvent`.

This runs every 2 seconds and processes around 50 events.  My issue is that I will soon be expanding this to 200+ events and there will be too much strain on the database because of so many parallel DB operations(there are currently 50 write operations/second.  Is there any hacky way I could use a single dbContext?  I must keep my async processing of the events or else it will take a minute+ to complete and my SLA is 2 seconds.

I am not concerned with "safety" features. For example, What if 2 events are trying to update the same record in my dbContext? This can never happen.

Comment: I would consider caching the new FanduelPosition and then when those reach a certain limit e.g. 50 records or a timer elapses e.g. 15 seconds.

Comment: A single context won't necessarily make this run any faster. You could possibly speed it up by caching the `fanduelPosition` object though.

Comment: @Nemavhidi Something like that would work if I only had new positions, I could just return all the new positions from the async function calls then add them all to the dbContext.  However, I also have updates as well.  How could I handle updating existing records?

Comment: @DavidG  I am not looking for speed improvements, my speed is as expected.  I am looking to lessen the strain on the database with less concurrent writes.  Right now I have 50 concurrent writes. If I had a single dbContext I would have 1 write.  I will be reaching my database concurrency limits as well once I expand my event list.

Comment: @user3533755, Assuming you like the bulk approach, I would do a similar thing for updates, as long as you have all the properties. There is a package called EfCoreBulkExtensions which greatly improves the performance of bulk inserts and actually has a context bulk update method as well.

Comment: But the reads will also be straining the database no? Still, you're not going to get a large bump in perf by bulk adding into a single DbContext. EF is pretty good at making the creation of a context and all backing services pretty efficient. You could also leverage connection pooling to help with that.

Comment: @DavidG True.  `dbContext.FanduelPositions.Where(s => s.Id == key).FirstOrDefault();` will this be a DB read everytime?  I would like to basically pull a full table cache at the start of the processing, do my async processing, then push all changes I made to that local cache at the end.  This way the only operations on the database are 1 read and 1 write.

Comment: That's not how databases work. It's still going to be lots of writes. Every DB `INSERT` is still executed one by one.

Comment: They are sent as a single bulk insert, if I check my DB resources when I insert 20k records vs 5 records, there is no difference.  Also I checked number of queries ran on the DB, 20k records vs 5 records is the same.

Comment: EF doesn't do bulk insert natively. It may send the SQL as one big block, but they are still executed individually.

Comment: Why is your code in a while loop? Seems like you'll end up calling `getEvents()` multiple times, doing the processing for each event multiple times...

Comment: @Kit because it processes the data constantly. Start -> process data -> write data -> process data -> write data -> etc.

Comment: @DavidG Gotcha, well either way,  I get almost no inserts/updates, every time I do a full data process of 50 events, I will get at most a few updates.  It is trivial.